# Insert data into intersection table

Tags: php, mysql, join, insert

So I have these 3 tables in my database :

```
    ACTORS :
->name     -varchar -primary key
->yob      -int     -primary key
->uploader -varchar

    MOVIES :
->title    -varchar -primary key
->yor      -int     -primary key
->uploader -varchar

    MOVIE_ACTORS(my intersection table for those 2) :
->movie_title -varchar -foreign key
->movie_yor   -int     -foreign key
->actor_name  -varchar -foreign key
->actor_yob   -int     -foreign key
```

I have 2 types of insertion in php by different forms :

**1)** By this one i introduce the whole movie in my database,among with some actors which are found in it's cast.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO movies (TITLE, YOR, UPLOADER) 
        VALUES ('".$title."', '".$release_date."', '".$uploader."')";
 mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
 for($i = 1; $i <= $actors_nr; $i++)
 {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO actors (NAME) VALUES ('".$actor[$i]."')";
   mysqli_query($connection,$sql); 
 }
```

**2)** By this one i introduce an actor in the database(if it doesn't exist,introduced with the movie,i introduce it;if it was created with the movie,i just update the database with the new data) :

```
    if($rowcount < 1)
  {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO actors (NAME, YOB, UPLOADER) 
         VALUES ('".$name."', '".$birth_year."', '".$uploader."');
    mysqli_query($connection,$sql);     
  }
 else
 {
   $sql = "UPDATE actors SET YOB='$birth_year', UPLOADER='$uploader'WHERE NAME='$name'";
   mysqli_query($connection,$sql);     
 }
?>
```

How do i introduce the datas in the intersection table in each of this cases ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do php for awhile so I give you pseudocode, a movie has many actors so you have to insert a row for each actor in the movie but information of the movie are the same in each row:

```
$actors = $movie->actors;
$sql = "INSERT INTO MOVIE_ACTORS (movie_title, movie_yor, actor_name,actor_yob) 
         VALUES"
foreach($actor in $actors)
{
   $sql += "($movie->title,$movie->yor,$actor->name,$actor->yob),"
}
// do an insert with this sql
```